# Flash Builder 4.6 Native extension Error

Tags: c, actionscript-3, serial-port, flash-builder, air-native-extension

i have an error that i dont understand why appear, the most weird is that happens sometimes but lately happens always, the code that i use is the same and i dont have make any changes to it, in fact i dont execute any code in the start of the application, i use buttons , so i dont get a reason with this error please help me, the error is a dialog that say:

Native extension Error: there are packaging errors/warning. Check each native extension in the Flex Build Packaging Page for each target platform. would you like to continue?

And when i click yes the program dont start, the debbuger show me the line:

[SWF] SerialCOMGame.swf - 2,121,630 bytes after decompression

but never start, i am using RS232 library for serial communication, before of get this error this work fine but i dont know what happen, my C code is:

```
/*
 * NativeSerialComunication.c
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 10, 2012
 *      Author: Diego Fernando
 */
#include "NativeSerialComunication.h"
int comport = 0;
int baudrate = 57600;
int buffsize = 4096;
unsigned char buffer[4096];
uint32_t comportOpened = 0;
FREObject IsSupported(FREContext ctx, void* functionData, uint32_t argc,
        FREObject argv[]) {
    FREObject result;
    uint32_t isSuppoerted = 1;
    FRENewObjectFromBool(isSuppoerted, &result);
    return result;
}

int startCOMListener() {
    if (!OpenComport(comport, baudrate)) {
        comportOpened = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void stopCOMListener() {
    CloseComport(comport);
    comportOpened = 0;
}

void COMListener(FREContext ctx) {
    uint8_t compbytes = 0;
    while (comportOpened) {
        compbytes = PollComport(comport, buffer, buffsize);
        FREDispatchStatusEventAsync(ctx, (const uint8_t *) "listening for data",(const uint8_t *)"datalistening");
        if (compbytes) {
            FREDispatchStatusEventAsync(ctx, (const uint8_t *) buffer,
                    (const uint8_t *) "datareceived");
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
FREObject startSerialListener(FREContext ctx, void* functionData, uint32_t argc,
        FREObject argv[]) {
    FREObject result;
    if (startCOMListener()) {
        CreateThread((LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL, 0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) COMListener, ctx, 0, NULL);
        FREDispatchStatusEventAsync(ctx, (const uint8_t *) "listener started",
                                    (const uint8_t *) "listenerstarted");
    }
    FRENewObjectFromBool(comportOpened, &result);
    return result;
}

FREObject stopSerialListener(FREContext ctx, void* functionData, uint32_t argc,
        FREObject argv[]) {
    FREObject result;
    stopCOMListener();
    FRENewObjectFromBool(comportOpened, &result);
    return result;
}

FREObject sendDataToSerialPort(FREContext ctx, void* functionData,
        uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[]) {
    FREObject result;
    uint32_t dataSended = 0;
    uint32_t dataToSend = 0;
    FREGetObjectAsUint32(argv[0],&dataToSend);
    printf("data to be sended %d",dataToSend);

    if (comportOpened && !SendByte(comport,dataToSend)) {
        dataSended = 1;
    }
    FRENewObjectFromBool(dataSended, &result);
    return result;
}

void MyContextInitializer(void* extData, const uint8_t* ctxType, FREContext ctx,
        uint32_t* numFunctionsToSet, const FRENamedFunction** functionsToSet) {

    *numFunctionsToSet = 4;

    FRENamedFunction* func = (FRENamedFunction*) malloc(
            sizeof(FRENamedFunction) * 4);
    func[0].name = (const uint8_t*) "isSupported";
    func[0].functionData = 0;
    func[0].function = &IsSupported;

    func[1].name = (const uint8_t*) "sendDataToSerialPort";
    func[1].functionData = 0;
    func[1].function = &sendDataToSerialPort;

    func[2].name = (const uint8_t*) "startSerialListener";
    func[2].functionData = 0;
    func[2].function = &startSerialListener;

    func[3].name = (const uint8_t*) "stopSerialListener";
    func[3].functionData = 0;
    func[3].function = &stopSerialListener;

    /*func[1].name = (const uint8_t*) "sayHelloWorld";
     func[1].functionData = 0;
     func[1].function = &sayHelloWorld;*/

    *functionsToSet = func;
}

void MyContextFinalizer(FREContext ctx) {
    return;
}

void initializer(void** extDataToSet,
        FREContextInitializer* ctxInitializerToSet,
        FREContextFinalizer* ctxFinalizerToSet) {
    extDataToSet = 0; // This example does not use any extension data.
    *ctxInitializerToSet = &MyContextInitializer;
    *ctxFinalizerToSet = &MyContextFinalizer;

}

void finalizer(void** extDataToSet) {
    stopCOMListener();
    return;
}
```

And this is my ActionScript code that use the native C code:

```
package com.nativeserialcomunication.driver
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.StatusEvent;
    import flash.external.ExtensionContext;

    public class NativeSerialComunication extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private var extensionContext:ExtensionContext;
        private var isSerialListenerStarted:Boolean = false;
        public function NativeSerialComunication(target:IEventDispatcher=null)
        {
            super(target);
            extensionContext =ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext("com.nativeserialcomunitacion.driver.NativeSerialComunitation","");
            extensionContext.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,statusHandle);
        }

        public function init():void{
            if(extensionContext.call("startSerialListener") as Boolean){
                isSerialListenerStarted = true;
                trace("serial listener started");
            }
            else{
                trace("no serial listener started");
            }
        }

        public function statusHandle(event:StatusEvent):void{
            trace("the event ("+event.level+") received, data:"+event.code);
        }

        public function isSupported():Boolean{
            return extensionContext.call("isSupported") as Boolean;
        }

        public function sendDataToSerialPort(data:uint):Boolean{
            return extensionContext.call("sendDataToSerialPort",data) as Boolean;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i like the looks of this...been using ArduinoConnector (http://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/wiki/Introduction) for direct serial communication but it has some issues with crashing in certain conditions.  diego, did you get this direct serial ANE working?  can you make it available for others?  thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The native extension package checkbox for your target platform(s) may need to be checked.

Navigate to:

Project Properties  -> Flex Build Packaging  ->  Apple iOS (or Android, etc.)

Select the Native Extensions tab and make sure "Package" is checked.

Comment: awesome my friend you are the best, save me lots of wasted time :D